# Upload file to Amazon S3 throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

I'm using Amazon .net sdk to upload files as streams to S3 , I've got "**Cannot close stream until all bytes are written**." exception on upload.
my code :

```
public void Upload(Stream fileStream, string path)
    {
            TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(Client);
            transferUtility.S3Client.PutBucket(new PutBucketRequest() { UseClientRegion = true }.WithBucketName("bucket"));
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
            .WithBucketName("bucket")
            .WithKey("key")
            .WithTimeout(100 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            .WithPartSize(10 * 1024 * 1024)
            .WithAutoCloseStream(true)
            .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite)
            .WithInputStream(fileStream) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;

            transferUtility.Upload(request);
    }
```

Note: I tried it with basics config which is just BucketName & Key, and added timeout, partsize ..etc but nothing changed.

Comment: How large are your files?

Comment: I tried it with small files & large ones.